# Cannot create a Reddit account

Tags: user-accounts, reddit

I'm seeing some weird behavior when I try to create a Reddit account.  It says the account name is acceptable / not taken, my passwords match, and I pass the CAPTCHA (I get an error when I don't) but when I submit the form it just disappears and I remain on the current page, not logged in.  Refreshing the page changes nothing and I cannot log into the account that should have been created.

I've tried clearing my cache and cookies, different browsers, different usernames and password formats, and different computers on different networks with absolutely no luck.  I have successfully created (and deleted) an account some months in the past, as well.  Has something important changed?  What should I try?

Comment: I was able to create an account today, and the reason wasn't apparent, so I think this should be closed.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug that couldn't be reproduced (per the OP).

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak to your situation in particular -- but it may be useful to note that I successfully established a Reddit account just yesterday, so the problem is not universal.

You're clearly a savvy user, and you've already tried just about everything I can think of -- but here are a couple of left-field ideas that you might consider:

1. Are you sure you're entering the information in the correct place (https://www.reddit.com/; then clicking on "login or register", which will open a pop-up dialog)? If you're working from a bookmark, it could be an out-of-date link at Reddit, or, worse, a phishing scheme.
2. I know you said you refreshed the page -- but I'm uncertain if this means the target page (after the submission) or the form page (on which you provided the account information). From your previous account creation activities at Reddit, you may have cached an old version of the form with a bad target link -- so you might want to refresh the form page if you didn't do so previously.
3. I know you said you provided different user names and passwords -- but you didn't mention providing a different e-mail address. Perhaps there is something about that e-mail that is confusing the Reddit system. You might try using a new e-mail that has never been submitted to Reddit before (maybe even one that you create for this purpose).

If I think of anything else, I'll follow up here. Good luck.

Comment: I'm visiting the site directly, and the form is overlaid on the page (the dialog you mention).  I've tried different emails as well as not giving one at all.